# Nodemon -L not working using npm script from package.json on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, package.json, nodemon, npm-scripts

I am trying to set up a development environment on docker. I am running code that I made from [this project](https://github.com/linnovate/mean).

I have seem several answers on stack-overflow  but none of them solves my issue.

My package.json script is as below.

```
"ng": "ng",
"serve": "node server",
"start": "concurrently -c \"yellow.bold,green.bold\" -n \"SERVER,BUILD\" \"nodemon --legacy-watch ./server/index.js\" \"ng build --watch\"",
"build": "ng build --prod",
// more code...
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g --force nodemon

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4043

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks as below:

```
services:
    app:
        container_name: express-ng-server
        restart: always
        image: express-ng-server-image
        build: .
        ports: 
            - '80:4043'
        expose:
            - 4043
```

When I do `docker-compose up` nodemon does react to code changes.

When I run `npm start` nodemon works as expected.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get nodemon to work in docker?

I am using the latest version of nodemon `"nodemon": "^2.0.4",`

Comment: The code won't change unless you rebuild the image, and if you rebuild the image you'll need to recreate the container.  I would only use tools like `nodemon` in a local-development environment, and not with Docker.

Comment: I was rebuilding the container with `docker-compose build`. But it still did not work. I guess I will follow your way of using nodemon; only in a local development environment and not with docker.